# Turning a string into list of positive and negative numbers

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, converters

If I have a string always in the form `'a,b,c,d,e'` where the letters are positive or negative numbers, e.g `'1,-2,3,4,-5'` and I want to turn it into the tuple e.g (1,-2,3,4,-5), how would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

One method would be to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('1,-2,3,4,-5')
(1, -2, 3, 4, -5)
```

Comment: interesting way! Great talk about SO, btw :)

Answer (score 4):

Split on `,` and map to `int()`:

```
map(int, inputstring.split(','))
```

This produces a list; if you need a tuple, just wrap it in a `tuple()` call:

```
tuple(map(int, inputstring.split(',')))
```

In Python 3, `map()` returns a generator, so you would use a list comprehension to produce the list:

```
[int(el) for el in inputstring.split(',')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputstring = '1,-2,3,4,-5'
>>> map(int, inputstring.split(','))
[1, -2, 3, 4, -5]
>>> tuple(map(int, inputstring.split(',')))
(1, -2, 3, 4, -5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
>>> inputlist = '1,-2,3,4,-5'
>>> tuple(int(x) for x in inputlist.split(','))
(1, -2, 3, 4, -5)
>>>
```